# Database error in Django admin interface on shared hosting

Tags: mysql, django, shared-hosting

I'm using django with MySQL on a shared hosting.
If I'm going in 'users' or 'groups' in administration panel, I see this [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNhWh.png):

"Database error. Your database is not configured correctly. Ensure that the appropriate tables were created, and that the corresponding user is allowed to access them."

MySQL database was created with the hosting panel, all tables were created with `syncdb` command.

Records can be added to table by admin panel (and PHPMyAdmin), but I can't see contents of the table through the Django admin panel.

- Django 1.6,
- Python 2.7.5
- settings.DEBUG=true

I have an access through 'ssh'.

FastCGI config:

```
import sys, os
venv = 'venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(venv, dict(__file__=venv))
sys.path.insert(0, "path to project")
sys.path.insert(0, "path to python2.7/")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "project.settings"
from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

Comment: Maybe your ``settings.DATABASES`` configuration is not good ? ``USER`` and ``PASSWORD``.

Comment: In this case the command "syncdb" would not work but it works

Comment: Maybe your *apache/www* user serving your Django project can't access to the Database ? What is your wsgi config ?

Comment: I just put root login/password in `settings.py`. How do i know about apache/www permittions?

Comment: I am pretty sure your hosting service has some documentation about the configuration into their environment. Which one is it by the way?

Comment: Mchost.ru. they have not very well documentation but not bad support and they are configure my fcgi script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However problem appears to be wrong configuration `.htaccess`. Thanks to hosting support.